# Magento - Delete the thousand separator in price

Tags: magento

I use Magento 1.4.2. and I want to delete the thousands separator in magento prices.

For example for in place of this price "1.375,50 €" I want to have "1375,50 €"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the folder `lib/Zend/Locale/Data` and find the file there that matches the language of the store. Search it for a `<numbers>` tag. The `<group>` tag probably affects the thousands separator, also look at altering the `<currencyFormat>` but a quick google tells me it isn't always used for currencies. (Did you try looking on the web before asking here?)

Clear the cache for good measure and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

to remove decimals , you just need to install the free module Currency Formatter Extension from Mageplaza here the link : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-currency-formatter/  .

Than you can disable the decimal from magento admin panel ->stores->configuration-> Mageplaza Extensions.

This worked for me in magento 2.3.3 installation .

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

For make trick when you have in `<group> </group>` thousand separator as `space` in locale main file (not territory file), e.g. `ru.xml` not `ru_RU.xml`
Go to the folder `lib/Zend/Locale/Data`, find your locale-related `.xml` and 
You need simply add second `space` to `<group>  </group>` tag.

This working fine if you use for example `ET_Currency_manager` useful module for price/currency management and have 'broken' thousand separator.